# SQL Join for cell content, not column name

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I read up on SQL Join but as far as I understand it, you can only join tables which have a column name in common.
I have information in two different tables, but the column name is different in each. I need to pull information on something which is only in one of the tables, but also need information from the other. So was looking to join/merge them.

Here is what I mean..

TABLE1:
http://postimg.org/image/hnd63c2f5/
The cell content `18599` in column `from_pin_id` also pertains to content in another table:

TABLE2:
http://postimg.org/image/apmu26l5z/

My question is how do I merge the two table details so that it recognizes `18599` is referring to the same thing, so that I can pull content on it from other columns in TABLE2?

I've looked through the codes on W3 but cannot find anything to what I need, as mentioned above, it seems to be just for joining tables with a common column:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Comment: " you can only join tables which have a column name in common" - Incorrect. The column values obviously need to be related but the name of the column does not matter.

Comment: Would that be detailed in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Just use a different column in one of the tables.  They have to have the same datatype of course.  For example you can't join a datetime column to a varchar column.

Comment: it's like you are trying to join two sets which have no common column but same data type of one column of your interest. You can use Intersect operator to find common values in two tables and then use these values to get main results.

Answer (score 0):

Change the table names and the columns that you select as needed.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.owner_user_id, table1.from_pin_id, table2.board_id
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.from_pin_id = table2.id
GROUP BY id, owner_user_id, from_pin_id, board_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as :

```
select * from table1 
where from_pin_id in 
(
    select from_pin_id 
    from table1
    intersect 
    select id
    from table2 
)
```

Intersect operator selects all elements that belong to both of the sets.